# Запрос к базе данных о пользователе

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, html5

Допустим id равен 12345.Мне нужно вытащить переменную boss у этого id.
и записать в переменную q.Как можно оформить такой запрос в базе данных?

[image: изображение как выглядит база данных]

```
$q = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id`, `boss` FROM `users` WHERE 1");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В SQL запросе после оператора WHERE нужно явно указать не значение, а выражение (сравнение, вхождение, условие).  В данном случае можно сравнить id с требуемым номером.

Далее нужно считать строку из запроса, в том случае, если число строк после обработки запроса больше 0, и получить значение переменной. В противном случае обработать ошибку.

```
$id = "12345";
$sql = "SELECT boss FROM users WHERE id=$id";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  $q = $row["boss"];
  echo "Boss: $q";
} else {
   echo "We have no record with id $id";
}
```

Старшие товарищи еще советуют делать все безопасно, и я с ними соглашусь - для таких языков как php, к сожалению, это огромная проблема, сравнимая с выстрелом в ногу: не использовать на прямую переменные в SQL запросах, так как это может закончится плачевно для данных в базе данных.

Если, к примеру у нас id передается как параметр get запроса, то

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT boss FROM users WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('d', $id);
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
   if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
      $q = $row["boss"];
      echo "Boss: $q";
   } else {
      echo "We have no record with id $id";
   }
}
```

Comment: Не помешает проверка, что $result не false, вдруг ошибки возникнут. И _никогда_ не подставляйте значение переменных непосредственно в текст запроса, _всегда_ используйте подготавливаемые выражения и привязку значений (http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Особенно в примерах на SO, на них учатся сотни людей и у всех у них в последствии будут дырявые сайты, допускающие SQL-инъекции, просто по тому, что они будут считать нормой такой код

Comment: @Mike абсолютно с вами согласен. В PHP я новичок - в основном занимаюсь golang-backend. Там этой проблемы нет.

Comment: можете посмотреть почему у меня так не срабатывает $q40 = $mysqli->query("SELECT `id`, `boss` FROM `users` WHERE WHERE id = 12345");                                             
                      name30="<? echo $q40; ?>"
alert(name30);

Comment: код не работает

Comment: @СергейАлександров В приведенных в ответе примерах после query, который только возвращает дескриптор запроса, идет еще fetch, который через этот дескриптор получает данные. И что то у вас странное с обрамлением php кода. Если все именно так как вы тут написали, то единственный php код тут это "echo $q40", остальное просто текст. по крайней мере не видно что бы остальной текст был в тегах "<php"

Comment: @SergeKior В mysqli execute к сожалению не принимает параметров для запроса, привязка только через bind_param. Вот PDO гораздо удобнее, при его использовании код такой как вы показали (вот такой бардак в php со всеми этими драйверами)